# Trigger a job and get the job log on the same page in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, build-pipeline, jenkinsfile, jenkins2

I would like to trigger the job in Jenkins and also get the log on the same page.

**E.g.** Kind of IDE where we can run the code in one side and get the output on the other side.

Are there any tools exists to fulfill this, or do we need to create it?

Comment: We have a use case where the dev wants to start a build and see right there, without clicking the results/log. I think you're asking that question also? The problem I noticed is that there's a time during which there is no job, and the build number can change before it starts. But maybe below plugin works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there exists a plugin to do exactly what you want: [Display console output plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/display-console-output).

However, I haven't tried this plugin myself, and it looks like this plugin is not well-maintained, so I cannot vouch for the quality of this plugin.

Comment: This plugin appears to show the latest [?] console log on the project page.

Comment: Is that not what you want?  That sounds to me like exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I'm not OP so will not speak for smc, but for me it might be! I have to try it out. ty!